# Through which method is the value invoked if magic getter is combined with getter

Tags: php, class, getter-setter, magic-methods

If I use it like this (outside of a class):

```
    $user_agent = $user->user_agent;
```

Method get_user_agent() is called in constructor.

Here magic __get calls method get_user_agent and not returning value of member variable user_agent.

How to avoid that?

```
class user
{
    private $user_agent;


    public function __get($key)
    {
        $value = null;

        if(method_exists($this, "get_$key"))
        {
            $value = $this->{"get_$key"}();
        }
        else
        {
            $value = $this->$key;
        }

        return $value;
    }


    public function get_user_agent()
    {
        $this->user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    }
```

Comment: You might consider using the `__set()` magic method as well, and storing these values in a different named variable, or within a stdClass.

Comment: I'm using it, but then all the member variables are set as public

Comment: Should I just return value of $this->user_agent in method get_user_agent?

Comment: As a note: I would say your method is a `setter` as it sets a member and does not return anything.

Comment: @insertusernamehere: You mean that I should name the method set_user_agent?

Comment: Yes, `setUserAgent()` to set the value and `getUserAgent` to return the value like `return $this->user_agent`. It might be confusing as you "*get*" the value from `$_SERVER` but you "*set*" your class member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return the value after setting it:

```
public function get_user_agent()
{
    $this->user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    return $this->user_agent;
}
```

But this is actually quite confusing, because you would not expect a method prefixed with 'get' to assign/define anything first before returning it. That's what `__set()` is for. In this case you probably even want to do it in the `__construct()` method:

```
class user
{
    private $user_agent;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    }

    public function __get($key) {

        if(method_exists($this, "get_$key"))  {
            return $this->{"get_$key"}();
        } else {
            return isset($this->{$key}) ? $this->{$key} : null;
        }

    }

    public function __set($var, $val) {
        //only allow to set existent attributes
        if( isset($this->{$var} ) ) {
            $this->{$var} = $val;
        }
    }

    public function get_user_agent() {
        return $this->user_agent;
    }
}
```

So the get-method is not the place to assign the attribute. In the example above, it is assign in the constructor. But you can change/assign it later if you want:

```
$user = new user(); //constructor-method is called, $user_agent is set now
```

But you can also set it yourself later on:

```
$user->user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];  //the magic __set()-method is called

echo 'Your user agent is: ' . $user->user_agent;
```

Comment: So if I use magic getters/setter I should not name other methods with prefix as get/set?

Comment: @troks No, you can do that if you want to, but I wanted to pint out that it's confusing if you actually set something in a function you only expect to get/return a value. You expect it only to read something and return it, without any side-effects. The values should be assigned either during the construction of the class or later through a setter, but not while actuelly reading the value. I've edited my answer and added a setter to make this more clear.

Comment: @Quasdunk: Not necessarily there are plenty of "lazy load" situations where you can fetch the value from something already exposed even though its not set on the class yet, especially if its supposed to be immutable from the outside beyond construction.

Comment: @prodigitalson You're absolutely right, that depends on the use case and it sure can be reasonable to lazy load something sometimes. But I guess you should only do this if you really know what you are doing, and I assume that the OP is rather at a beginner level at the moment, so I think it might be a better approach to learn it the 'oldschool' way first before diving into micro optimisation. Good point though, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Quasdunk: True enough on the beginner thing.

Comment: Are attributes that are set trough magic __set always public or is a way to set them private?

Comment: @troks `__get()` and `__set()` are only called if the method or property is inaccessible, for instance, because it's private. Just leave the `__set()`-method blank if you don't want any private attributes to be modified. Also, please note that the `__set()` method is not meant to declare new class attributes, it's only meant to modify existent ones. If you need more/other attributes for the class, declare them just like/where you declared $user_agent and tell it whether you want it to be public, private or protected. (I hope this answers your question, not quite sure waht you're asking)

Comment: '__set() method is not meant to declare new class attributes' answered my question, thx!

Comment: @troks Always glad to help :) Maybe you should also have a closer look at the manual for a deeper understanding: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set - I'm pretty bad at explaining stuff :-P

Comment: I disagree with that last sentence. Your answers are pretty good. As a beginner is difficult to find the right answers in the php manual.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that `get_user_agent` doesn't actually return anything. you could try:

```
 public function get_user_agent()
 {
     $this->user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
     return $this->user_agent;
 }
```